# Socket Timeout is not working in Servlet

Tags: java, sockets, servlets, timeout

I have a Java servlet which tries to connect to the source(Using request ip address).

Method is as :

```
String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();

private void connect(String ip) throws SocketException, IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, Constant.PORT));
    }
```

Now if it doesn't connect withint a second it should throw exception but it is not throwing exception in one second but takes a while like 10-15 seconds.

Could someone help why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SO_TIMEOUT (which is set by [socket.setSoTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)) only affects socket.getInputStream().read(). To specify connect timeout, [specify a second parameter to socket.connect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29):

```
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, Constant.PORT), 1000);
```